# How to query for records that have a certain count within a timespan

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in which I store a log of every request to a web site. Every time a page is requested, a record is inserted. I now want to analyze the data in the log to detect possible automated (non-human) requests. The criteria I need to use is x number of requests within y seconds by an individual user.

So, the data looks like this:

| **Page**          | **UserId** | **Date**                           |
| /Page1.htm | 001      | 2014-06-02 11:03 AM |
| /Page2.htm | 001      | 2014-06-02 11:03 AM |
| /Page1.htm | 002      | 2014-06-02 11:04 AM |
| /Page3.htm | 001      | 2014-06-02 11:04 AM |
| /Page2.htm | 002      | 2014-06-02 11:05 AM |
| /Page4.htm | 001      | 2014-06-02 11:05 AM |
| /Page5.htm | 001      | 2014-06-02 11:07 AM |
| /Page3.htm | 002      | 2014-06-02 11:15 AM |

So, I wanted to get all UserIDs that made 5 or more requests within any 5 second timespan. How can I get that? Is this even possible with SQL alone?

I don't have access to the web server logs or anything else other than the SQL Server database.

Comment: What is the version of your SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the query which you are looking for:

```
SELECT
    T1.Page, 
    T1.UserId, 
    T1.Date, 
    MIN(T2.Date) AS Date2, 
    DATEDIFF(minute, T1.Date, MIN(T2.Date)) AS DaysDiff,
    COUNT(*) RequestCount
FROM
    [STO24541450] T1 LEFT JOIN [STO24541450] T2
    ON T1.UserId = T2.UserId AND T2.Date > T1.Date
GROUP BY
    T1.Page, T1.UserId, T1.Date
HAVING 
    DATEDIFF(minute, T1.Date, MIN(T2.Date)) >= 5 AND COUNT(*) >= 5;
```

Comment: You have a typo: should be `DATEDIFF(minute, T1.Date, MIN(T2.Date)) <= 5` (**less** or equal)

Answer (score 0):

I would probably group by the time range and UserId and grab any with a count greater than 5.

```
select count(*),
       UserId,
       dateadd(SECOND, DATEDIFF(SECOND, '01-jan-1970', [date])/5*5, '01-jan-1970') 
from   [LogTable]
group by UserId, DATEDIFF(SECOND, '01-jan-1970', [date])/5
having count(1) > 5
```

The above will return the same UserId for each period in which the user has made more than 5 requests. If you're only interested in the userId's and not when or how many times they breached the conditions you could simplify the above to

```
select distinct(UserId)
from   [LogTable]
group by UserId, DATEDIFF(SECOND, '01-jan-1970', [date])/5
having count(1) > 5
```

Comment: *within any 5 second timespan*

Comment: @PM 77 - good point, I missed the word _any_. My solution will work in 5 second timespans from 0 seconds to 55 seconds each minute but it won't capture cases where for example 2 hits are at 03 seconds and another 3 hits are at 06 seconds as they'd fall into different groups.

Answer (score -1):

This is untested but should hopefully give you an idea on how to proceed.

```
SELECT UserId, COUNT(UserId) as AccessCount
     (SELECT UserId FROM AccessLogTable WHERE Date BETWEEN startDate AND endDate) a
GROUP BY UserId HAVING COUNT(UserId) > x
```

What we're doing here is using a subquery to first select the subset of records (your y criteria) that are of interest. This will then be encapsulated in an external query where you would do a group by UserId having count(userid) > x.

Comment: `startDate` and `endDate` are not known